# jQuery delay inside loops

Tags: jquery, delay

I want to make a timer in jQuery, I want change the value of span each second I make like this, but it delay is not working.

```
 function startTimer(daysRemain,hoursRemain,minutesRemain,secondsRemain){

            while(secondsRemain < 60){
               secondsRemain++;
               $("span.secondRemain").delay(1000).text(secondsRemain);  //change value of seconds each one second 
                // I try this way too!
               /* setTimeout(function(){
                    $("span.secondRemain").text(secondsRemain);
                },1000);*/

            }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`delay` is only for the fx queue.

A standard timer is as follows

```
var t = 0;
setInterval(function () {
    $('div').text(t);
    t += 1;
},1000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J9Zwa/

Comment: mmm you are right, but I tried the setTimeOut way too and also doesn't work.

Comment: `setTimeout` will only call once.  You can either call `setTimeout` again within the the initial `setTimeout` or use `setInterval`  see my edit for a basic timer example.

Answer (score 1):

`.delay()` doesn't delay your running javascript.  It goes into the animation queue and when the queue gets to that operation, it sets a timer for the delay time and doesn't proceed to the next operation in the queue until that much time has elapsed.

As such, you can't use it in your loop to make a javascript delay.  You will need to use `setTimeout()` like this.

```
function startTimer(daysRemain,hoursRemain,minutesRemain,secondsRemain) {

     function nextTime() {
         if (secondsRemain < 60){
             secondsRemain++;
             $("span.secondRemain").text(secondsRemain);  //change value of seconds each one second 
             setTimeout(nextTime, 1000);
         }
     }
     nextTime();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
setInterval(function(){
   $("span.secondRemain").text(secondsRemain);
},1000);
```